# The LINQ expression could not be translated while using array of dates

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following LINQ code with me

```
List<DateTime?> selectedDates = new List<DateTime?>();

    var sql = _dbContext.Seat
.Where(s => s.IsActive == true && s.FloorId == 1404)
.Select(s => new
{
    s.SeatId,
    s.Name,
    s.radius,
    s.XCoordinate,
    s.YCoordinate,
    s.FloorId,
    BookedFlag =
    selectedDates.Any(sd =>
    _dbContext.SeatBooking.Any(sb => sb.BookedDate == sd) ||
    _dbContext.GuestBookings.Any(gb => gb.StartDate <= sd && gb.EndDate >= sd) ||
    _dbContext.SeatReservation.Any(sr => sr.StartDate <= sd && sr.EndDate >= sd))
});
```

I need to check if each date in the `selectedDates` falls within the startdate and enddate range. This should be an equivalent of

```
    SELECT S.seatid,
       S.NAME,
       S.radius,
       S.xcoordinate,
       S.ycoordinate,
       S.floorid,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT bookedid
                     FROM   seatbooking SB
                     WHERE  S.seatid = SB.seatid
                            AND bookeddate IN( '01-18-2024', '01-19-2024' ))
               OR EXISTS(SELECT *
                         FROM   guestbookings GB
                         WHERE  S.seatid = GB.seatid
                                AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                           FROM   (VALUES ('01-18-2024'),
                                                          ('01-19-2024')) AS
                                                  DateList(
                                                  datevalue)
                                           WHERE  DateList.datevalue >=
                                                  GB.startdate
                                                  AND DateList.datevalue <=
                        GB.enddate))
               OR EXISTS(SELECT *
                         FROM   seatreservation SR
                         WHERE  S.seatid = SR.seatid
                                AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                            FROM   (VALUES ('01-18-2024'),
                                                           ('01-19-2024')) AS
                                                   DateList(
                                                   datevalue)
                                            WHERE  DateList.datevalue >=
                                                   SR.startdate
                                                   AND DateList.datevalue <=
                                           SR.enddate))THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END BookedFlag
FROM   seat S
WHERE  S.isactive = 1
       AND S.floorid = 1404
```

I am getting the following exception here

> The LINQ expression 'sd => DbSet()
> .Any(s0 => s0.BookedDate == sd) || DbSet()
> .Any(g => g.StartDate <= sd && g.EndDate >= sd) || DbSet()
> .Any(s1 => s1.StartDate <= sd && s1.EndDate >= sd)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: If you try `selectedDates.Any(sd =>
    _dbContext.SeatBooking.Any(sb => sb.BookedDate == sd) ||
    _dbContext.GuestBookings.Any(gb => gb.StartDate <= sd && gb.EndDate >= sd) ||
    _dbContext.SeatReservation.Any(sr => sr.StartDate <= sd && sr.EndDate >= sd))` separately with some `sd` value being hard-coded, then is it running?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes It yields 'true'

Comment: If you rewrite (for the sake of an experiment) `selectedDates.Any(sd => ...)` to `selectedDates.Any(sd => true)`, will it throw an exception?

Comment: Yes same exception

Comment: Then it seems Any is not supported in this context. Is it possible to do the selection without the Any and then loop the result and compute it separately?

Comment: EF supports only `Contains` with local collections that's why it is not translatable.

Answer (score 0):

Your where condition is missing

```
List<DateTime?> selectedDates = new List<DateTime?>();

var sql = _dbContext.Seat
.Where(s => s.IsActive == true && s.FloorId == 1404)
.Select(s => new
{
    s.SeatId,
    s.Name,
    s.radius,
    s.XCoordinate,
    s.YCoordinate,
    s.FloorId,
    BookedFlag =
    selectedDates.Any(sd =>
    _dbContext.SeatBooking.Where(x=>x.seatid=s.seatid).Any(sb => sb.BookedDate == sd) ||
    _dbContext.GuestBookings.Where(x=>x.seatid=s.seatid).Any(gb => gb.StartDate <= sd && gb.EndDate >= sd) ||
    _dbContext.SeatReservation.Where(x=>x.seatid=s.seatid).Any(sr => sr.StartDate <= sd && sr.EndDate >= sd))
});
```